# nginx fastest non-http redirection

Tags: nginx, redirect

I use nginx

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

and it works well. However it doesn't have to look up for the `$uri` file.
I saw that it is possible to use empty string instead of `$uri`, which could be faster, i.e.

```
location / {
    try_files '' /index.html;
}
```

but it just doesn't work for me. So how to do it the fastest way? Or maybe using rewrite would be faster?

Comment: I very much doubt you would be able to see any difference in speed, but an empty string doesn't really make any sense - if you don't need to match `$uri` simply delete it.

Comment: There is no need to define a location block for / to effectively duplicate the index directive. If in doubt - use the [debug log](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) and look at what each config permutation does under the hood. Irrespective though you _aren't_ going to have any significant effect (positive at least) with these kind of hacks, file lookups are cached anyway - so it's only memory access not file system.